# Emphasis tag doesn't work for Google text-to-speech

Tags: google-text-to-speech

The emphasis tag has no effect on the generated sound file for Google's text-to-speech cloud service, when used in SSML mode. Does anyone know if this is by design or a bug? Both these sentences sound exactly the same:

```
<speak>
  You need to figure out what works best for <emphasis level="strong">you</emphasis>.
  <emphasis level="strong">You</emphasis> need to figure out what works best for you.
</speak>
```

I've tried it in both calling the REST API, and using the demo form here:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech

However, the phoneme tag works, so it is not ignoring all SSML tags.

I am using the "en-US-Neural2-J" voice.

Answer (score 1):

*Something spoken(emphasized) singularly is different than when spoken in multiple words or sentence.* Similar problem is discussed in this Github [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-text-to-speech/issues/237).

I tried with the following example:

```
<speak>
  You need to figure out what works best for <emphasis level="strong">you</emphasis>.
<break time="1000ms"/>
  You need to figure out what works best for <emphasis level="strong">you and Sheldon</emphasis>.
</speak>
```

Here, you would be able to recognize the emphasis tag working perfectly with combination of multiple words ie. `you and Sheldon` when compared to just single word `you`.

You can even try `prosody` tag, which can be easily used to enunciate and put stress on specific words.

For example:

```
<speak>
You need to figure out what works best for <prosody rate="slow" pitch="-3st">you and Sheldon</prosody>, because he is your brother.
</speak>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have played around with the prosody tag, using the rate, pitch and volume attributes, but I can't get it to sound natural. The emphasis tag is hit and miss. Sometimes you can hear the emphasis, but in most cases you can't. What I'm trying to do is something very basic in languages; to shift the emphasis to different words in a sentence. "HE did it to me" vs "He did it to ME" vs "He DID it to me". Strange that this is not possible with Google text-to-speech.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with emotions. The Azure TTS has some amazing features with the express/style element. You can’t use it with each voice. This is something missing until now in the Google TTS

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US' xmlns:mstts = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts'> 
<voice name = "en-US-JaneNeural">
<mstts:express-as style="whispering" styledegree="2,00">
You have the force
</mstts:express-as>
</voice>
```